# How to Audit an Authenticated Profile Page using SEO PowerSuite - Website Auditor or Screaming Frog?

Tags: web, audit

I'm currently working on auditing a profile page that requires authentication. The issue I'm facing is that the audit tool I'm using, when crawling "example.com/profile," gets redirected to "example.com/sign-in" and only audits the sign-in page. I'm seeking guidance on how to correctly audit the profile page. Specifically, I need assistance with setting up the crawl settings in SEO PowerSuite - Website Auditor or configuring the authentication settings in Screaming Frog. Alternatively, I would appreciate recommendations for other tools that can help me accomplish this task.

For SEO PowerSuite - Website Auditor, I'm looking for assistance with the following:

Crawl Setting:
[image: Crawler Setting]

As for Screaming Frog, I need help configuring the authentication settings:

Authentication Setting:
[image: Authentication Setting]

Thank you in advance for your valuable suggestions and guidance.